# Whys does Alt($\alpha)=\alpha \iff \alpha \in \Lambda^k (V^*) $hold for $ k=0 ?$

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

The following is according to Lee's introduction to smooth manifolds chapters 12 and 14.

Let V be a vector space, $k\in \Bbb Z_{\ge 0}, \alpha $ a covariant k-tensor, i.e. $\alpha \in T^k(V^*)$ a multilinear map from $V\times...\times V\to \Bbb R$ .

$\Lambda^k (V^*)$ is the subspace of alternating covariant rank-k tensors

I proved the following property for $k \ge 2$.

Alt($\alpha)=\alpha \iff \alpha \in \Lambda^k (V^*)$

where Alt($\alpha)$ is a projection called alternation defined as

[image]

But the book states it is true for $k \ge 0$. My question if about the $k=0$ case. I know that the right side of the implication is vacuosly true, that is every covariant rank-0 tensor is alternating. (here $\Lambda^k (V^*) = \Bbb R $ ) so for the statement to be true, I would need the left side to be true as well, wouldn't I? so Alt($\alpha)=\alpha$ should be true, but then I would have an empty sum, wouldn't I? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum) And that is defined to be 0, so I would get $\alpha=0$ and therefore $0=\alpha \iff \alpha \in \Lambda^0 V^*$

**Which is not true as $\alpha$ can be any real number. How do I resolve this situation?**

Comment: Why do you write "$p=0$" in the title and once in the question when there is no $p$ anywhere else?  You meant $k = 0$.

Comment: yes, I fixed it, thank you

Comment: If we think of $S_n$ as the set of bijections $\{1, \ldots, n\} \to \{1, \ldots, n\}$, $S_0$ contains precisely the empty map $\emptyset \to \emptyset$, which is consistent with the convention $0! = 1$. Of course, we must take the sign of that map to be $+1$.

Comment: @TravisWillse so we don't have an empty sum but a sum of one element just like in the case $p=1$? since $S_0$ has cardinality 1?

Comment: @TravisWillse But if we must count the empty map, the cardinality of $S_n$, or better of the set of bijections would be n!+1, but we usually take it to have cardinality n!?

Comment: @darkside No. The empty map is clearly not in $S_n$ for $n>0$.

Comment: You shouldn't think too much about it; $\Lambda^0(V^*) = \mathbb{R}$ plays more the role of a "limit case" in order to avoid exceptions in formulas than anything else.

Comment: @darkside blargoner's right: The domain of any such map is $\{1, \ldots, n\}$, which is not the domain of the empty map for $n > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If we think of $S_n$ as the set (in fact, group) of bijections $\{1, \ldots, n\} \to \{1, \ldots, n\}$, $S_0$ contains precisely the empty map $e : \varnothing \to \varnothing$, which is consistent with the convention $0! = 1$. The empty map is the (empty) product of zero transpositions we should take its sign to be $+1$, giving
$$\operatorname{Alt} \alpha = \sum_{\sigma \in S_0} (\operatorname{sgn} \sigma) ({}^\sigma\alpha) = (\operatorname{sgn} e) ({}^e\alpha) = \alpha$$
as desired.